# Timer Events, Increments, and Resets in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, count, timer

A timer is being used in my C# application to determine if an expected event has occured in a timely fassion.  This is how I am currently attempting to do this:

```
// At some point in the application where the triggering event has just occured.
   // Now, the expected event should happen within the next second.
   timeout = false;
   timer1.Interval = 1000; // Set timeout for 1 second.
   timer1.Start();

timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timeout = true;
}

// At some point in the application where the expected event has occured.
   timer1.Stop();

// At a later point in the application where the timeout is
// checked, before procedding.
   if ( timeout )
   {
      // Do something.
   }
```

Now, what I am wondering is when the `Start()` or `Stop()` member methods are called, does that cause the timer count to reset?  I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [Stop()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.stop.aspx) it effectively resets the timer back to 0, from the linked page:

> Calling Start  after you have disabled
>   a Timer  by calling Stop will cause
>   the Timer  to restart the interrupted
>   interval. If your Timer  is set for a
>   5000-millisecond interval, and you
>   call Stop at around 3000 milliseconds,
>   calling Start  will cause the Timer 
>   to wait 5000 milliseconds before
>   raising the Tick  event.

Comment: Thanks.  I did look at the MSDN article, but I must have missed this tidbit of information.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.stop%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> Calling Start  after you have disabled a Timer  by calling Stop will cause the Timer  to restart the interrupted interval. If your Timer  is set for a 5000-millisecond interval, and you call Stop at around 3000 milliseconds, calling Start  will cause the Timer  to wait 5000 milliseconds before raising the Tick  event.